# html page in iframe can't find its css file

Tags: html, css, django

I'm working with Django framework.

At least the people at the Django mailing list seem to think it is an HTML problem.

My main (top page) html page includes the following code:

```
<div>
  <iframe id="iframe1" src="welcome"></iframe>
```

The `src` is so terse because the call is handled through a Django view which has the  code:

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def mainPage(request):
    return render(request, 'main/main2.html')

def welcome(request):
    return render(request, 'main/welcome.html')
```

The CSS files are in a static files directory. The main page loads its CSS file okay. The `welcome.html` file loads okay but does not load its CSS file. It has the following standard header:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Welcome To UUCLB Archives</title>
    *<!--Setup stylesheet-->*
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static  /welcomePage.css"/>

    <!-- The setup for jQuery -->
    <script src="/static/jquery.js"></script>
</head>
```

The `welcome.html` CSS file does not load nor is there any indication that `welcomePage.css` is having any effect whatsoever.

Why would the main page (called through the same view) load and use its CSS file while the `welcome.html` file called by the `iframe` does not.

I hope I have all of the relevant code snippets included hear. If not please ask for more.

```
Debian OS (Stretch)
Firefox browser
Eclipse IDE
Bluefish HTML editor
Python 3.7
Django 1.9
```

Any help will be sincerely appreciated.

Comment: Did you notice that you have two spaces in `/static  /welcomePage.css` ?

Comment: The space is an artifact of the cut and paste. Not actually in the program. I did remove the leading / as not being necessary. This didn't change anything.